Google Calendar API per-user quota limit reached even when using quotaUser
I've started getting these 403 errors when trying to add events using the Google Calendar API:
    {
      domain: 'usageLimits',
      reason: 'quotaExceeded',
      message: 'Calendar usage limits exceeded.'
    }

This happens when trying to add events to a service user calendar, which has lots of events due to serving as a placeholder user for booking of multiple resources.
I'm aware of how quotas should be managed and how to use the quotaUser parameter to distribute requests, however, unfortunately in one of our code paths the quotaUser was missing. This likely led to the quota being surpassed for the service account user.
However, also after fixing the issue and adding a properly distributed quotaUser to the calls, they continue to fail.
In fact, even if I authenticate as our service account and try to add a calendar event to the service account's own calendar with a quotaUser such as foobar, it still fails.
My interpretation is that the previously exceeded quota for the service user impacts the target calendar itself as well (i.e., regardless of who's making the request to add events to the calendar, the calendar itself is in a state of "exceeded"). But this is not documented anywhere. The documentation just says to make sure to distribute your requests' quota contribution by using quotaUser properly.
Note that other calendars within the tenant work fine, when making requests onto actual end users' calendars there is no issue, regardless of whether the request is made with the user's token subject or the service account's, and also regardless of whether the quotaUser is the end user, the service account, or just a random string.
So, again, it seems to me like it's the calendar itself of the service account that's been flagged - I'm not allowed to create more events in that calendar regardless of who makes the request.
Can someone confirm what's happening here, and whether this issue will simply resolve automatically after a while when that calendar has "cooled down"?
BTW, when checking my API quotas in the console, the quota for requests per minute is fine (I'm at like 1.3%). The quotas for "per-user" is however not displayed, nor is there any way to request an increase to it. Why is that?

Based on what you have shared with your post it seems that you were just simply hit by Exponential Back offs and it will just work again once it "cooled down", About your other Quota and Limits questions it is best handled and answered by a Google Support. Just to help you get started on the right path to correcting this I would suggest visiting this article: Google API quota

Calendar usage limits exceeded sounds more like a limit within google calendar and not strictly to the API.   There are a max number of events that can be inserted into a calendar per day by a user.
